# Allocating specific GPUs using Pytorch in ImageNet example code

Tags: python, pytorch

PyTorch has an example [here](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/master/imagenet/main.py) on how to train networks on ImageNet. At line 102, we have `ngpus_per_node = torch.cuda.device_count()` which takes all the GPU's to allocate the computation.

I have 8 GPUs and the first four of them are busy. How to modify the code so that I can pass the indices of the available GPUs?

Comment: When you run the python file, you can use `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=4,5,6,7 python3 run.py ....`. This way, only the last 4 GPUs will be available to the code.

Comment: @akshayk07: When I do that I get `RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 392.00 MiB (GPU 0; 11.91 GiB total capacity; 10.38 GiB already allocated; 366.56 MiB free; 10.95 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)` which means python still tries to use 0-th GPU.

Comment: Sometimes the nvidia-smi IDs and the CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES IDs are reversed. So, you might want to also try `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1,2,3` and see if that actually works.

Comment: @akshayk07: the last one does not work either.